# Will the source mapping in Google Chrome push to Error.stack

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, stack-trace, source-maps

Within Google Chrome, I was wondering if stack traces will, in the future, provide mapping support. Currently, using source maps, throwing an error will provide the line number link to my TypeScript files, however... When calling the Error.stack, it gives me the JavaScript lines and files.

Here's a reference picture: http://puu.sh/4DTOG.png

As you'll notice, the actual line the error is on is linked to the TypeScript file, but the stack trace links to the JavaScript files.

Comment: That image is no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inherent technical limitation. However I don't think it is planned. For reasons like, when the stack trace contains code that is not TypeScript (or lacks a sourcemap) etc.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I think they could easily swap a js file for a ts file that has a corresponding map file, when producing the stack. Do you know where a feature request like this can be submitted?

Answer (score 4):

This bug is fixed in chromium 42 :)

Cf https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357958 .